# Android 7 jni open() fails + usb camera controls

Tags: android, camera, java-native-interface, native, ioctl

I was using this example with ioctl on android 4.4, 5.1
https://github.com/theicfire/simplewebcam/blob/master/jni/ImageProc.c

I am using this interface to get manual control over parameters like contrast, gain, exposure, white level and etc.
when I tried to move the app to android 7 the fd file fails to open.

```
fd = open (dev_name, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
```

Is there any way to fix this?

I have checked and camera2.api doesn't allow controls over the parameters I need from the camera, and the native code fails because of this error.

edit:
to be more precise, I am using a USB camera connected to the tablet, and android 7 doesn't let met get the device FD even though I am using chmod 666 or 777 to set the permission. is there any way around it or other way to get the controls over exposure, contrast, gain, white lvl?

this is the code I added in the java part, the code fails in the canRead() part

```
    private void InitCameraDevice() throws Exception {
        //set permissions to all /dev/video devices before checking them
        General.RunAsRoot("chmod 666 /dev/video*");

        NativeUtils.setLogName(General.getLogFileName());

        File dir = new File("/dev");
        File[] videoDevFiles = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.startsWith("video");
            }
        });

        boolean cameraFound = false;
        for (File deviceFile : videoDevFiles) {
            // Process file
            if(deviceFile.canRead()) {
                cameraFound = (NativeUtils.prepareCamera(deviceFile.getAbsolutePath(), frameWidth, frameHeight) != -1);
                if (cameraFound)
                    break;
            }
            else
                General.logd(STREAM_THREAD_TAG, "Insufficient permissions on [" +
                        deviceFile.getAbsolutePath() +"].");
        }

        if(!cameraFound)
            throw new Exception("UVC Camera not found!");
    }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: to be more precise, I am using a USB camera connected to the tablet,
and android 7 doesnt let met get the device FD even though i am using chmod 666 or 777 to set the permission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Android USB manager APIs to get the FD for your USB device; accessing the /dev node directly bypasses Android's permission enforcement (see the [USB guide here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#permission-d)) for USB device access.

Applications having access to the /dev node is therefore a security vulnerability that's locked down in more recent Android releases.

Once you have the FD for a USB device from the Java USB API, you can manipulate it in native code if you'd like.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work for me, I have added the code and where it fails

Comment: You're not using the Android USB manager APIs in your code sample; accessing the /dev/video nodes directly is not generally allowed.  Even on a rooted device, SELinux permissions may still cause you trouble, and certainly this won't work on a regular OS image.

Comment: can you please show me how can i get the fd of the camera using the usb api, so both the open() and canRead() wont fail because of permissions?
thanks

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection